# How to dynamically set SSH key in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, laravel-5.5

I am managing a network of multiple servers and want to connect with servers using SSH keys. I found out that we can give path to SSH key in Laravel's **remote.php** config file like this:

```
.
.
'key' => '/path/to/ssh/key'
.
.
```

But as I want to connect with many servers, I can't set up single private key for all servers as it won't be secure. So, the only thing I can think of is setting SSH keys dynamically. Till now, I used to login using password which I can set dynamically using `Config::set();` but I don't know a way to set up SSH key dynamically.

We can use `Config::set();` in this case too, But that way, I'll have to store all SSH keys in specific directory with server identity. However, I want to save SSH keys in the database because it's more stable and backup-friendly.

I also thought about updating SSH key file with Server's SSH key before connecting to server but it will create overhead that I don't want because it will slow down connections because it will write SSH key file every time it connected with the remote server through SSH.

Is there any way I can store SSH keys in database as well as set it dynamically?

Comment: 1) laravel has no `config/remote.php` by default 2) could you show some example code of how you would determine which ssh key to set? 3) any relevant (including not yet working) code you could also attach to the post?

Comment: 1. I know laravel does not provide `config/remote.php` by default. I am using laravelcollective's remote package to handle all my connections. I would like to set SSH keys just like we set a password. I don't want to define a path of the SSH key but I want to put SSH key content directly into the `key` directive in remote.php. That way, I can set SSH key dynamically directly from the database.

Comment: I don't have code because here logic is missing, without logic, we can't make code, obviously. However, I can connect by defining SSH key file in the config but I don't want to update SSH key file with new key every time I try to connect with the server.

Comment: Allright, typing a large answer now, hang on :)

Comment: @p01ymath Honestly never use this package on my projects, but after do some reading at the code, I think your scenario is possible. `keytext` config is what you are missing. The source code that worth to read https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote/blob/5.5/config/remote.php#L35 and https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote/blob/5.5/src/SecLibGateway.php#L229

Comment: So, Instead of giving a path of the key file in `key` directive, I can put key file content in `keytext` directive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of ssh'ing using your mentioned package while using the model as a 'key':

Ignore the service provider added by the package:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "Collective\\Remote\\RemoteServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
},
```

Add a `getConfig()` method to your model that contains the ssh details:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Connection extends Model
{
    public function getConfig(): array {
        return [
            'host'      => '',
            'username'  => '',
            'password'  => '',
            'key'       => '',
            'keytext'   => $this->key,
            'keyphrase' => '',
            'agent'     => '',
            'timeout'   => 10,
        ];
    }
}
```

Create a file called `App\Overrides\RemoteManager`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Overrides;

class RemoteManager extends \Collective\Remote\RemoteManager
{
    protected function getConfig($model)
    {
        return $model->getConfig();
    }
}
```

Create a new service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Overrides\RemoteManager;

class RemoteServiceProvider extends \Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('remote', function ($app) {
            return new RemoteManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

Add `\App\Providers\RemoteServiceProvider::class,` to `config/app.php` under "package service providers"

Example code of how this will work:

```
$connection = \App\Models\Connection::find(1);
SSH::into($connection)->run([
    'echo "Hello world!"',
]);
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks!